# Error when installing apollo/client in react-native app

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I am building a react native cli app and I want to use @apollo/client to reach the graphql server. But when running these commands

```
npm install @apollo/client graphql
```

I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: parcel-transfer@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: graphql@14.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^0.11.3 || ^0.12.3 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from apollo-link@1.2.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/apollo-link
npm ERR!     apollo-link@"^1.2.14" from graphql-tools@4.0.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/graphql-tools
npm ERR!       graphql-tools@"^4.0.5" from json-graphql-server@2.3.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/json-graphql-server
npm ERR!         json-graphql-server@"^2.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     apollo-link@"^1.0.0" from apollo-client@2.6.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/json-graphql-server/node_modules/apollo-client
npm ERR!       apollo-client@"^2.6.4" from json-graphql-server@2.3.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/json-graphql-server
npm ERR!         json-graphql-server@"^2.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from apollo-utilities@1.3.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/apollo-utilities
npm ERR!     apollo-utilities@"^1.3.0" from apollo-link@1.2.14
npm ERR!     node_modules/apollo-link
npm ERR!       apollo-link@"^1.2.14" from graphql-tools@4.0.8
npm ERR!       node_modules/graphql-tools
npm ERR!         graphql-tools@"^4.0.5" from json-graphql-server@2.3.2
npm ERR!         node_modules/json-graphql-server
npm ERR!       1 more (apollo-client)
npm ERR!     apollo-utilities@"^1.0.1" from graphql-tools@4.0.8
npm ERR!     node_modules/graphql-tools
npm ERR!       graphql-tools@"^4.0.5" from json-graphql-server@2.3.2
npm ERR!       node_modules/json-graphql-server
npm ERR!         json-graphql-server@"^2.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     2 more (apollo-client, apollo-cache)
npm ERR!   8 more (express-graphql, graphql-tag, graphql-tools, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @apollo/client@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: graphql@16.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   peer graphql@"^15.7.2 || ^16.0.0" from subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/subscriptions-transport-ws
npm ERR!     peerOptional subscriptions-transport-ws@"^0.9.0 || ^0.11.0" from @apollo/client@3.8.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/client
npm ERR!       @apollo/client@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/paulin/.npm/_logs/2023-09-04T22_36_13_101Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/paulin/.npm/_logs/2023-09-04T22_36_13_101Z-debug-0.log
paulin@bkjp-hp-envy:~/projects/Betfien-Inc/parcel-transfer/frontend/android/app$
```

Does react native comes with garphql and apollo already installed ?
How to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. there was an old version of json-graphql-server in my package.json file. I deleted it and try to install apollo/client and every thing is ok.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).